# Laravel: custom Admin:auth storing data with authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use the below code to work with admin model. By default it works like this:

**PostController:**

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'about' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',

    ]);
    auth()->User()->posts()-`>create($data);`

    dd(request()->all());
}
```

And I am trying to get it work with admin like this:

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'about' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    auth()->Admin()->posts()->create($data);

 dd(request()->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no method called 'admin()' in [auth()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-auth) you can use method 'user()' instead to get the current logged user:

```
auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
```

Comment: that works with the user model but how can i access the admin model which uses auth as well

Answer (score 0):

To handle my current situation. This is what i came up with so that the admin can as well post through authentication.
I added a variable for the user_id  to relate with the post in the request we are getting from post form.

#### PostController

```
  public function store( Request $request )
{
    $user = Auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->id(); 
    if (is_null($user)){
        $user = Auth::guard('web')->id();
    }
    $request->request->add(['user_id' => $user] ); // Here a request is given a varible either for the admin or user
    $data = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'about' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',

    ]);
   
    
    \App\Post::create($data);
       
        dd(request()->all());
```